# how to interpret learning curve in machine learning?

Tags: python, classification, evaluation, overfitting-underfitting

those're the learning curves for each algorithm I used. i'm working on my report and i'm confused how to interpret the curve.
I used multi label classification algorithms.
this is the learning curve of binary relevance the classifier is KNeighborsClassifier.
[image: 1st learning curve]

the second one is the curve of classifier chain using DecisionTreeClassifier
[image: 2nd learning curve]

and the last one is the curve of LabelPowerset using GaussianNB
[image: 3rd learning curve]

which one is the best? because the accuracy and the F1 score are good results

Comment: It's suspicious that the second one already gives you 100% Training score with few samples. You might be overfitting. How are the three methods performing in the test set?

Comment: yeah true the dataset in not big. i got good result in the classification report. i think the second one is overfitting how can i proveit

Answer (score 0):

Learning curves are a tool to finding which models benefit from increasing training data. In other words, they indicate whether a model, with an increased dataset, will give better results.

The best curve in my opinion is the one that gives the best normalized score in a minimum training example. It also has to converge fast enough to a good score.